# I am trying to make a label display a phone number, that will work as a link for mobile users to dial from their devices, how can I do this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, label

I am creating a mobile website where the user can view the contact numbers for certain companies. The company details are received from a database then displayed on the webpage depending on the company ID. I want to allow the user to click/tap on the number and then their mobile will ring or at least display that number for them to ring/save.

I have just started a Software Development apprenticeship - a huge leap from what I'm used too - so I am pretty clueless with ASP.NET as I have never used it before. I've gone from using Notepad++ to this haha.

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div class="contactTelephone">
        <p>
            <asp:Label ID="lblTelephoneNumber" runat="server" />
        </p>
    </div>
```

Here is my background code (thought i'd show you most of it, if it's too much I apologize in advance, it's only half of the code but the lower code seems to this part)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
      if (!Page.IsPostBack) 
      {
          // Try and parse value from the query string
          int contactId = 0;
          int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["contactID"], out contactId);

          // Bind details
          BindContactDetails(contactId);
          BindContactActivites(contactId);
      }
  }

  // Create a new instance of the contact helper
  ContactHelper cHelper = new ContactHelper();

  public void BindContactActivites(int contactID) 
  {
      if (contactID > 0) 
      {
          List < CompanyActivityDetails > contactActivites = cHelper.GetContactsActivities(contactID);
          rptContactActivity.DataSource = contactActivites;
          rptContactActivity.DataBind();
      }
  }

  public void BindContactDetails(int contactId) 
  {
      // Make sure id is valid
      if (contactId > 0) 
      { // Get a single contact record
          contact contactDetails = cHelper.GetContact(contactId);

          // lbSendEmail.CommandArgument = contactId.ToString();

          // Make sure object is valid
          if (contactDetails != null) 
          {
              lblContactName.Text = contactDetails.firstName + " " + contactDetails.lastName;
              lblTelephoneNumber.Text = contactDetails.telephone;

              /* This is the relevant part here? ^^^^ */
```

Thank you, this is my first SO post, let me know if I've missed anything out.

Comment: You need to convert your `span` to a link similar to this: `<a href="tel:the-number-to-call">the-number-to-call</a>`

Comment: A pretty easy google... http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/click-to-call-links-mobile-browsers

Comment: I have already Googled it, and I can't get those methods to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

So...

```
<div class="contactTelephone">
        <p>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="hypTelephoneNumber" runat="server" NavigateUrl="tel:+61262777860" Text="+61262777860" />
        </p>
</div>
```

In code behind

```
  public void BindContactDetails(int contactId) 
  {
      // Make sure id is valid
      if (contactId > 0) 
      { // Get a single contact record
          contact contactDetails = cHelper.GetContact(contactId);

          // lbSendEmail.CommandArgument = contactId.ToString();

          // Make sure object is valid
          if (contactDetails != null) 
          {
              lblContactName.Text = contactDetails.firstName + " " + contactDetails.lastName;
              hypTelephoneNumber.Text = contactDetails.telephone;
              hypTelephoneNumber.NavigateUrl = string.Format(
                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                  "tel:{0}",
                  contactDetails.telephone);
```

Comment: I get what you mean, It's just I don't know what the numbers are as they change depending on the ID of the contact, so I can't fill them in as +61262777860, for example.

Comment: Could you be less vague please?

Comment: In the code behind meaning the .cs file for the markup page.  e.g. in the page_load as the example in the answer above

Comment: @Zelda Seriously... If this answer is vague, I don't know what you are expecting. Maybe someone to code the whole thing for you, and this is not the purpose of the site.

Comment: @Zelda A bit of effort is always welcome. You can easily adapt this answer to your code. In your `BindContactDetails` you have all the details you need.

Comment: @MelanciaUK FYI I did add the code behind page_load code to the answer after the Zelda's vague comment

Comment: @MelenciaUK No need to talk like I can't read your answer? I am incredibly new to this and it's a huge leap from what I'm used too. I know what code behind is, if I didn't I wouldn't have it in my question. I just wanted to know what went into the code behind, as the <a> tag didn't work for me. I don't want someone to 'code the whole thing' I just want some guidance. I do appreciate the help from Mick.

Comment: Also, this is my first question on this site, I wasn't 100% sure what to expect. I'll just stick to asking help from my colleagues from now on I think.

Comment: @Zelda It's a bit obvious, at least for someone that's writing a solution in ASP.NET/C#, that you would use a `asp:HyperLink` instead of a regular anchor (which would be fine, but then...). What's so difficult in adding a `tel:` at the beginning of your `NavigateUrl`? That's the whole point here. And I didn't criticize Mick's answer. It's complete and functional. I even upvoted it.

Comment: @MelenciaUK Like I said, I've just started a software development apprenticeship, I've only used Notepad++ before and this is all new to me. Don't make assumptions, because it isn't 'obvious' to me. I never said  you criticized Micks answer I just stated I appreciate his help

Comment: @Zelda Fair enough. You have the solution now anyway. Thanks to Mick.

Comment: @Zelda Notepad is great but Visual Studio is better, and you can download it legally for free from Microsoft...

http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=40787

Comment: @MelenciaUK Microsoft Visual is what I'm currently using

Answer (score 0):

This might help - 3rd from the top on the Googles!

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-quick-tip-phone-number-links--mobile-7667

or

http://allwebco-templates.com/support/S_smartphone-link.htm

Comment: I am not 100% sure that is what I'm looking for? I've Googled it already but it made no sense as to how I'd fit that tag in my code, as I've tried and it wouldn't work.